# jquery json reorder with leading zero

Tags: jquery, ajax, arrays, json

I've a bunch of data that is sorted by weeknumber. The php script uses

```
$week = date('W', strtotime($date));
```

to get a weeknumber with leading zero's. (thats not in the spec, but that is what I get).
The problem is with a range of weeks say from 6 till 15. This will result in array keys like: 06,07,08,09,10,11,12,13,14,15. The json my page receives is ordere like this: 10,11,12,13,14,15,06,07,08,09
The array is correct in php script even when I send it. The Firebug console shows a received data like:

```
{"06":{"my":6.6,"other":5.5},"07":{"my":5.9,"other":5.5},"08":{"my":5.8,"other":5.2},"09":{"my":6.2,"other":5.6},"10":{"my":6.1,"other":5.6},"11":{"my":6,"other":5.3},"12":{"my":6.1,"other":5.6},"13":{"my":5.9,"other":5.7},"14":{"my":5.8,"other":5.7},"15":{"my":6.5,"other":5.7},"16":{"my":6.4,"other":5.7}}
```

which is correct. In the same console, you can see the json, which results in the wrong order like this: 10,11,12,13,14,15,06,07,08,09. That's also the order how

```
 $.each(scores, function(week, scores) {
```

will iterate over it. I suspect that the trailing zero's get treated as strings and thus end up after the number.

Can I somehow trick jQuery to do less work to the received data? And leave the order as is?

Comment: Keys order inside of object is not guaranteed by JS. Maybe you want to sent array of objects from the server-side?

Comment: Evidence to support @IgorDymov's correct statement - https://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=164

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to solve the problem with javascript clientside. I just needed to get rid of this leading zero. to make sure there are no integer-string conversions...
This is very easy. After creating the weeknumbers..

```
$week = date('W', strtotime($date));
$def_array[(int)$week][$from] = round($scores['total'] / 10, 1);
```

As you can see, I've converted the $week to an int, which loses the trailing zero and thus the order for all values.

Answer (score -1):

first load all object to array

```
var tmpArr = [];
var sortedObjArr = [];

$.each(scores, function(week, scores) {
 tmpArr.push(parseInt(week));
}

tmpArr = tmpArr.sort();

for(var i in tmpArr){
 sortedObjArr.push({i:scores[i]});
}
```

sortedObjArr is your sorted objects Array.

Comment: you can also reverse array as per your requirements. using tmpArr.sort().reverse(); :)

Comment: firstly, you will get items with leading zero parsed as octal numbers, which is wrong. And then you will sort numbers array without comparer, which is wrong too.

Comment: Note that I have used parseInt, 1. it parses any string starting with 0 as a number only. not octal number 2. sort operation of array here knows there is only numbers in array so it sorts as per the order 1->2->3 ... n only. so no comparator required

Comment: parseInt: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt
Array.sort: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: Sorry, Actually i have tested it on my latest chrome browser console. & both things worked correctly.